# Lambda error : Invalid value "undefined" for header "x-request-id"

Tags: http, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, nuxt.js

I deployed Nuxt project on AWS Lambda function.

I followed this reference - https://dev.to/adnanrahic/a-crash-course-on-serverless-side-rendering-with-vuejs-nuxtjs-and-aws-lambda-1nk4

Everything looks good, however, when I test lambda function on aws console, there is 500 error:

[image: Lambda test log image]

There is no error in api-gateway logs.
Why this error came up and how to solve it?

I found that `'x-request-id'` is made by client side. Then, should I add `'x-request-id'` to api-gateway config?